# Show block on specific pages URL attribute

Tags: 6, blocks

I am looking to show a certain block on a page only when a certain url attribute (using alias)

For example:

I have pages /foo/*

I want to show the The block when viewing /foo/*?showblock

Where * is a wildcard.

I have tried typing this into my "Show block on specific pages" portion of the block settings, but the block never shows. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP visibility on your block settings to achieve this. Drupal block's visibility does not provide the functionality to display blocks based on parameters after ? (aside from ?q= of course) so you need to do this with custom PHP.

Set your block visibility to use PHP as the markup and place this in your code:

```
<?php 
// Show the block if the 'showblock' attribute is available
if (!empty($_GET['showblock'])) {
  return TRUE;
}
return FALSE;

?>
```

Happy Programming!

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely worth looking at the [Context](http://www.drupal.org/project/context) module.  This should help you no-end with problems like this.

That said, TheRealWebGuy has a better answer if this is just a one-off, but it's always better to know these things :-)